# Images not caching with Firebase url but caching with other

Tags: swift, caching, firebase

I have little problem. I got caching to work with the following `URL`:

```
let URL = NSURL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/master/images/kingfisher-\(indexPath.row + 1).jpg")!
```

But can't get it to work like this with this `URL`:

```
FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("\(productImageref!).png").downloadURLWithCompletion({(url, error)in

            if error != nil{
                print(error)
                return
            }else{

                cell.snusProductImageView.kf_setImageWithURL(url , placeholderImage: nil,
                    optionsInfo: [.Transition(ImageTransition.Fade(1))],
                    progressBlock: { receivedSize, totalSize in
                        print("\(indexPath.row + 1): \(receivedSize)/\(totalSize)")
                    },
                    completionHandler: { image, error, cacheType, imageURL in
                        print("\(indexPath.row + 1): Finished")

                })
            }
        })
```

What I am doing wrong here? Can you point me to the right direction? For caching I use the 3rd party library "**KingFisher**"

**Edit**: Firebase guy Mike McDonald's quote

> "The Github one has Cache-Control: max-age=300 while Firebase Storage
>   doesn't have cache control set by default (you can set it when you
>   upload the file, or change it by updating metadata), so I assume
>   that's why KingFisher isn't caching it."

KingFisher owner [quotes](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/issues/403#issuecomment-240339989).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I got them caching was that I had to write all image `url-s` into `JSON` like this:

```
.setValue(url!.absoluteString)
```

And then read those as `url-s`

Answer (score 3):

Like Firebase guy Mike McDonald said I directly set the cache-control when uploading the image to the Firebase storage. Then it will be cached correctly when loading it later.

(Configuration: Swift3, Firebase Storage 3.11.0)

```
let storage = FIRStorage.storage()

let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: yourFirebaseStorageReferenceURL)

let imageRef = storageRef.child("profileImages/\(imageUUID).jpg")

let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

// THIS is the important part
metadata.cacheControl = "public,max-age=2592000"

let uploadTask = imageRef.put(imageData, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
   if let error = error
   {
        completion(.failure(error as NSError))
   }

   guard let metadata = metadata, let downloadURL = metadata.downloadURL()?.absoluteString else {
        // Handle upload error
        return
   }

   // Handle successful upload
}
```

When I download the image, the cache-control is set

[image]